# How to exit Kiosk Mode in Edge programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I'm developing a system that runs in Edge (school's default browser), the browser launches in Kiosk mode from a desktop shortcut

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk [www.program-name.com](http://www.program-name.com) --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen

On the landing page, I can exit the program no problem with a close button using

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.close();" value="Close">
```

Once you proceed into the program, next page onwards, window.close no longer works. The only way to quit is by using Alt + F4 or pressing the Start key and right clicking the Edge icon

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Developer Tools console, you'll find this message when the window doesn't close by `window.close()`:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.

The message is clear. There're some restrictions when using `window.close()` to close window. In Chromium, `window.close()` succeeds if the new window/tab has an [opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) or if the back/forward stack contains fewer than two entries. The limitation of `window.close()` is for security and user-experience. For more detailed information, you can refer to [this blog](https://textslashplain.com/2021/02/04/window-close-restrictions/).

The only way to close the proceed window programmatically is opening the window by `window.open()`. For example, if you want to open a new window by clicking a link, you can use the code like below:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('test.html', '_blank')">link</a>
```

Then on **test.html** you can use `window.close()` to close the window.